# Understanding a simple configuration file for initramfs

Tags: initramfs

Can somebody explain me what is happening in the following?

```
# This is a very simple, default initramfs

    dir /dev 0755 0 0
    nod /dev/console 0600 0 0 c 5 1
    nod /dev/tty 0666 0 0 c 5 0
    nod /dev/null 0600 0 0 c 1 3
    nod /dev/mem 0600 0 0 c 1 1
    nod /dev/kmem 0600 0 0 c 1 2
    nod /dev/zero 0600 0 0 c 1 5
    nod /dev/random 0600 0 0 c 1 8
    nod /dev/urandom 0600 0 0 c 1 9

    dir /dev/pts 0755 0 0
    nod /dev/ptmx 0666 0 0 c 5 2

    nod /dev/ttyS0 0666 0 0 c 4 64
    nod /dev/ttyS1 0666 0 0 c 4 65
    nod /dev/ttyS2 0666 0 0 c 4 66

    dir /bin 755 0 0
    dir /proc 755 0 0

    file /bin/hello ${INSTALL_ROOT}/projects/${SAMPLE}/hello/hello 755 0 0
    slink /bin/init hello 777 0 0
```

What are we trying to achieve here actually?

This is similar to [this one](https://github.com/tkgunji/linux-cortexm-1.12.0-dev/blob/master/projects/networking/networking.initramfs)

Generally it is clear to me that we are trying to run (hello ) from init (last line in code).

Comment: This looks like a configuration file for [populating `initramfs`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) with various nodes, directories etc. **We** are not trying to achieve anything (assuming you refer to a combined effort between you and me).

Answer (score 2):

This file is an input file for the
gen_init_cpio program in the kernel source tree.

It generates a cpio archive which is suitable for [initramfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) with the files/dirs/[devices(=nodes)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file)/... listed in the input file.

The syntax is

```
file <name> <location> <mode> <uid> <gid> [<hard links>]
dir <name> <mode> <uid> <gid>\n
nod <name> <mode> <uid> <gid> <dev_type> <maj> <min>
slink <name> <target> <mode> <uid> <gid>
```

etc.

Which programs are actually run on boot, depends on the `init` program in the initramfs. Here the `init` program is a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) to `hello`.

Answer (score 2):

@jofel has already answered the what it is question with admirable accuracy - what it should achieve, though, is the handoff from kernelspace to userspace. When the kernel loads it ensures all systems are operational then it looks for `init.` Without `init` your system's boot would never get off the ground - you would never be able to interact with the machine.

Some years ago the kernel developers decided they were tired of supporting 1001 and different possible configurations for root devices - it was simply becoming too complicated to handle booting a computer due to the sheer number of possible root file systems and root device type combinations. So they gave up trying.

`Initramfs` is builtin to every linux kernel since 2.6. In every case since then userspace begins there - the kernel hands control of the computer system over to `init`, sits back to watch the fireworks and washes its hands of the whole affair.

The directory tree described by the file in your question is a Linux root directory that is compiled into the kernel itself. It is the only root device the kernel will bother looking for; all of the rest is up to `init.`