# How to run scripts on headless startup?

Tags: debian, startup

How can I run a shell script when my Raspberry Pi starts up headless?

I don't want it to be dependent on booting into a console, or logging in, etc. It will literally be plugged into Ethernet and power, nothing else.

I saw [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up) on RPi SE. The answer was really thorough, but depended on things like logging in, booting to desktop, or booting to console.

How can I run a script on powerup, even if none of these things happen?

Thanks!

evamvid

Comment: What is your `init`?

Comment: @mikeserv Is that a file?

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123491/understanding-a-simple-configuration-file-for-initramfs/123517#123517  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118377/when-does-a-shell-get-executed-during-the-linux-startup-process/118382#118382

Comment: @mikeserv the OP is (probably) using raspbian which  (probably) uses sysvinit.

Comment: @terdon I'm actually using Occidentalis (which is based heavily on Raspbian).

Comment: @mikeserv So yeah, I guess I'm using sysvinit

Comment: @terdon if true, then the answer involves simply adding the necessary actions into scripts in `/etc/init.d/`. Right?

Comment: @evamvid that's the kind of thing you should include in the question itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can either add the script to your rc.local file located in /etc/, or create an init script.

One of the easiest ways to create an init script is to use 'pleaserun' . You'll want to use `sysv` as your platform target. https://github.com/jordansissel/pleaserun

Answer (score 1):

The option he provides for running a script when you boot to the console will work on a headless installation without requiring a user to log in.  It should work with the setup you described.

The other option in a regular Debian install is to edit the /etc/rc.local file, which is run on boot.  Creating an init.d script is a cleaner solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a script to run upon bootup then just stick the call to this script in the file, `/etc/rc.local`. This script is run upon your system booting up.