# Are there technical limitations preventing root=UUID=<filesystem-uuid> support?

Tags: linux-kernel, uuid

There is no code in `kernel-source/init/do_mounts.c` for mounting a filesystem by its UUID, however there is code for mounting a filesystem by that filesystem's partition's UUID.

Are there any technical limitations preventing `root=UUID=<uuid>` support from becoming a reality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I specify my root fs with a UUID?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93767/why-cant-i-specify-my-root-fs-with-a-uuid)

Comment: @JuliePelletier, it's not, because in my case, I know that the kernel does not support the filesystem's UUID because it doesn't have the code, I want to know why nobody has added that support yet. I want to know if there is something that's blocking people from adding that support. Because of that, the question you linked does not have an answer for my question.