# Kernel panic - not syncing: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) after building a kernel without initramfs

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, grub, kernel-panic, panic

While trying to install KISS Linux (a distribution which doesn't use (or at least doesn't by default) an initramfs), a distribution that requires you to build your own kernel, I always get the same kernel panic message, no matter what configuration I try. I tried enabling all the right device drivers for my SATA/SCSI/ATA controllers to no avail. I'm still unsure if the problem is my GRUB configuration or my kernel configuration, or some mix of both.

I found a post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93767/why-cant-i-specify-my-root-fs-with-a-uuid) saying that to find the root device without an initramfs, you have to use PARTUUID for the `root` kernel parameter, like this:
`root=PARTUUID=SSSSSSSS-PP`. I tried that (along with several different kernel configurations), but nothing seems to work. No matter what I did nothing about the kernel panic message would change, and the logs would be the exact same.

```
[~] λ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
```

```
[~] λ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    50M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0 111.3G  0 part
└─sda3   8:3    0   499M  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 931.5G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0 443.2G  0 part /home/void/hdd1
├─sdc2   8:34   0   250G  0 part
└─sdc3   8:35   0 238.3G  0 part /mnt/kiss
sdd      8:48   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   0 931.5G  0 part
```

Comment: Having the disk hardware name/brand/product, the relevant kernel options and/or components to handle this hardware, and the parameters given to the kernel at boot would surely help. The boot kernel messages up to the panic too.