# When will grub2's feature_platform_search_hint might be "No"

Tags: grub2

In self-generated `grub.cfg`, there is a lot of

```
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ] ...

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy]...

if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]...
```

My believe is that it is checking if the feature is present or not in the past when the answer might be false, like when grub2 was under development. But after so many years, will they ever be false in any case?

I'm more interested in the `$feature_platform_search_hint`, and as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/936546/843820),

> The predefined variables such as `feature_platform_search_hint` are hardcoded in the normal module at build time, and are essentially undocumented except by studying the source code. In current versions of grub, these variables are defined to be y at all times, so these variables seem to indicate support for specific features of a given grub version, and testing them can be done to write grub.cfg files that work with multiple versions of grub.

What I don't understand is why the self-generated `grub.cfg` has to be such over-complicated. E.g.,

Will I ever need to worry about the `$feature_platform_search_hint` now and in the future? If I manually write my own [maintenance free Grub2 menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673586/), do I have to repeat the self-generated grub.cfg like:

```
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt8 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt8 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt8  23cbdbaf-9bc8-49d0-a483-1ce445cf6fb4
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 23cbdbaf-9bc8-49d0-a483-1ce445cf6fb4
        fi
```

OK I just always use the `--hint` parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Reposting from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177035/843820):

> The list of features is maintained as `features` global variable in [`normal/main.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/log/grub-core/normal/main.c). `feature_platform_search_hint` has been available since GRUB 2.00 (released 2012)*(ten years ago)*. So the conditional code checking for this feature is pointless in all modern Linux distributions.
>
> At the time of this writing *(Sep 27 '19)*, the latest feature added was `feature_timeout_style`, available since 2.02-beta1.

I repeat, ***"the conditional code checking for this feature is pointless in all modern Linux distributions"***.

Comment: What is the conclusion? That 'else' branches in grub.cfg can safely be deleted (and delete the rest of the 'if' construct)? Or conversely, only keep the 'else' branches in grub.cfg (and delete the rest of the 'if' construct)? (For example, it makes for huge simplification during debugging boot problems.)

Comment: Yes @PeterMortensen, the entire conditional code checking is useless and can be deleted, not only the else branches, but the 'if' part as well, as _these variables are defined to be y **at all times**_, and yes it will surely makes for huge simplification of grub.cfg writing and debugging, which I've already tested myself.